# PuTTy + SSH fails with 'Server refused our key' the first time, but succeeds on second time

Tags: ssh, putty

I set up a Ubuntu server with OpenSSH and added my public key (generated with PuTTyGen) to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. I also configured and saved a PuTTy session to use the public key. However, I receive the following message when connecting:

```
Using username "phil".
Server refused our key
phil@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX's password:
```

I know the account password, so I can still log in.

The funny thing: While the first PuTTy instance is connected, I can open *another* PuTTy instance using the same session profile. This time, PuTTy succeeds:

```
Using username "phil".
Authenticating with public key "rsa-key-20190809"
Passphrase for key "rsa-key-20190809":
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-21-generic x86_64)
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out my encrypted `/home/` directory was the issue. For anyone who has similar issues in the future, here's a [description of the cause and suggested fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723712/passwordless-ssh-only-works-when-im-already-logged-in-on-ssh/723908#723908).